# Display div in another frame

Tags: javascript, css, html, frames

I have an index file containing a frameset:

```
<frameset border="1" frameborder="0" framespacing="0" rows="7%,93%">
  <frame src="index_top.htm" scrolling="no" marginwidth="0"
  marginheight="0" noresize name="top" target="_self">
    <frame name="main" src="index_main.html"
    scrolling="auto" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
  <noframes>
```

The `index_top` file looks as following (just the relevant parts):

```
<table width="100%" border="0" align="left" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="3" class="menyrad">
  <tr valign="middle" align="center">
    <td width="10%" id="homenav"><a href="framsida_test.html" onClick="changeClass(1)">Furniture home</a></td>
    <td width="10%" colspan="6">Currently browsing: <i id="mainlink"><span id="header">Select page</span><div id="linkdiv"><p><a href="coffee.html" id="link1" onClick="changeHeader(2)">Coffee tables</a></p><p>
<a href="side.html" id="link2" onClick="changeHeader(3)">Side tables</a></p><p><a href="stand.html" id="link3" onClick="changeHeader(4)">Stand tables</a></p><p>
<a href="dinner.html" id="link4" onClick="changeHeader(5)">Dinner tables</a></p><p><a href="sp.html" id="link5" onClick="changeHeader(6)">Stools/Pedestals</a></p></div></i></td>
    <td width="4%" id="galleriesnav"><a href="galleries.html" onClick="changeClass(2)">Galleries</a></td>
    <td width="4%" id="pressnav"><a href="press.html" onClick="changeClass(3)">Press</a></td>
    <td width="4%" id="factsnav"><a href="facts.html" onClick="changeClass(4)">Facts</a></td>
    <td width="4%" id="contactnav"><a href="contact.php" onClick="changeClass(5)">Contact</a></td>
    <td width="10%"><a href="http://www.carlson.se" target="_new">About artist Carlson</a></td>
  </tr>    
 </table>
```

The relevant CSS for `index_top`:

```
#linkdiv
{
    position:absolute;
    visibility:hidden;
    left:502px;
    width:100px;
    height:130px;
    background-color:#FFF;
    border-style:solid;
    border-color:black;
    border-width:2px;
    font-style:normal;

}

#header
{
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    width:100px;
}



#link1, #link2, #link3, #link4, #link5, #link6
{
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
    width:100%;
    display:block;
    outline:0;
}

#link1:hover, #link2:hover, #link3:hover, #link4:hover, #link5:hover, #link6:hover
{
    width:100%;
    color:#FFF;
    font-weight:bold;
}

#mainlink:hover #linkdiv
{
    visibility:visible;
}
```

Aaaaand the JavaScript:

```
function changeClass(Index)
{
    var ids = new Array("null","homenav","galleriesnav","pressnav","factsnav","contactnav");
    var color = new Array("null","#c9a900","#4814a9","#71a28a","#ac27a9","#998f86");
    var i=1;
    var length = ids.length;
    while (i<length)
    {
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).style.backgroundColor = '#FFF';
        document.getElementById(ids[i]).className = "blacklink";
        document.getElementById(ids[Index]).style.backgroundColor =color[Index];
        document.getElementById(ids[Index]).className = "whitelink";
        i++;
    }

}

function changeHeader(HeadIndex)
{
    var headers = new Array("null","Select page","Coffee tables","Side tables","Stand tables","Dinner tables","Stools","Pedestals");
    var colors = new Array("null","#f32837","#0085cf","#00aa86","#c99900","c42695","#617f90");
    document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = headers[HeadIndex];
    if (HeadIndex > 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("header").style.fontWeight = "bold";
        document.getElementById("header").style.color = "#FFF";
        document.getElementById("header").style.backgroundColor = colors[HeadIndex];
        document.getElementById("header").style.fontStyle = "normal";
    }

}
```

So, my problem here (sorry for the huge amount of code), is that when you try to hover over the "select page" text, the hidden `div` is being displayed... but under the main frame. Thus, it's impossible to press the links. How can I display the `div` OVER the main frame so it's clickable? Is it possible even?

Comment: have you thought about displaying the div as a modal?

Comment: next question: why frames? What's the advantage vs using divs that scroll? That would make this a lot easier.

Comment: Elaborate on your first comment? Dont know what a modal is. And it's a very old site built by my dad using only frontpage, as he knows no HTML and such. Im simply helping him out improving it. Changing it from frames to divs at this point in time would take very much time I believe

Comment: I see. This is really going to be tricky. Honestly you'd probably save yourself time by rebuilding this site in current technologies.

Comment: to answer your question, modal is called 'overlay' in this example: http://jquerytools.org/demos/overlay/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the link, I'll check into it. What you said is probably true though, I was hoping that wouldnt be the answer haha. Thank you!

Comment: I'm going to post a possible solution below, which might solve the problem in the short term.

Comment: more info on modal: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_window

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include your show/hide div in index.html OUTSIDE of the frame. Then use css positioning and z-index to force it to appear above the frames.